# creating new partition for backup

Tags: centos, lvm, partition, mount

I got a  new server form hosting company.  It has 2x2tb hard drives.

I told the provider I would be using one drive for data/OS and the other for backup.Before doing offsite  backup.

I moved all my files and data over from the old server and then i decided to setup a backup.I need to create a mount but i  just realized the server has been setup in this config

`df -h` shows this.

```
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg-root  1.8T   68G  1.7T   4% /
tmpfs                3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1            243M   94M  137M  41% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg-tmp   976M  1.3M  924M   1% /tmp
```

`lsblk` shows this

```
    NAME               MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                  8:0    0  1.8T  0 disk
sda1                 8:1    0  250M  0 part /boot
sdb                  8:16   0  1.8T  0 disk
sdb1                 8:17   0  1.8T  0 part
  vg-root (dm-0) 253:0    0  1.8T  0 lvm  /
  vg-swap (dm-1) 253:1    0  7.8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  vg-tmp (dm-2)  253:2    0    1G  0 lvm  /tmp
```

`fdisk -l` shows

```
Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 31 sectors/track, 494247 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 7905 * 512 = 4047360 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00062874

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          66      256000   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00083ac1

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1      243202  1953513472   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/vg-root: 1991.0 GB, 1990952222720 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 242052 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/mapper/vg-swap: 8355 MB, 8355053568 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 1015 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000


Disk /dev/mapper/vg-tmp: 1073 MB, 1073741824 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 130 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000
```

`pvs` shows

```
 PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize PFree
  /dev/sdb1  vg   lvm2 a--  1.82t    0
```

I have been reading online about LVM and  by what I understand is that the system is installed on `sdb` while `sda` has only got the boot partition installed.

As i already  already moved the data across, removing lVM would mean reinstalling OS.

the other option  was to 
1. remove  boot partition to  sdb 
2. create a large  partition on sda and  use that for backup.

I am not sure which option is better. if i go with option b then how do it .If backup partition sits on the boot partition, as the disk will be used daily for backup, is the risk of failure high..  what happens  to boot partition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question comes a-two:

What i recommend: sda contains boot partition sda1 (250MB) + unallocated partition sda (1.8TB), so create your backup on sda, by doing 2. below

boot partition WILL NOT of any significance be affected by your daily backups, this is simply because sda and sda1 themselves are separate partitions, and you will just have the added overhead of backup (perhaps once off a day?), if so, this would be by far better than a an everyday disk where boot and data (OS, Apps etc) reside on the same device. So no worries about overheard from backups

With regards to either take **Option A** or **Option B**

1. **Option B**: Remove boot partition to sdb:
   please have a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/3402/how-to-move-boot-and-root-partitions-to-another-drive. or lookup "moving boot partition from one drive to the other"
2. **Option A**: Create a large partition on sda:

You need to read on "LVM on CentOS", you must have a specific question on this, otherwise your question will not be regarded as "useful, since there will be not much research"

- checklist to quickly do LVM: https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Cluster_Logical_Volume_Manager/LV_create.html
- In-depth article to help you understand LVM in CentOS: https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Cluster_Logical_Volume_Manager/LVM_CLI.html

So i'll say, take option 2 on my list above, and lookup for help to do LVM using existing or new partitions to create filesystems.

Comment: thanks for you feedback....i went with option 2 . created a primary partition with  fdisk. formatted the new partition and created a mount point..I didn't use vgextend .. Or should i  use vgextend ?

Comment: No, vgextend would certainly be for adding volumes right? You didn't add a volume right? If the file system (mount point) is now accessible (i.e. you can see it using `bdf` or `df` command, and you followed the steps as prescribed with the option you took (fdisk), thats fine for now, you're welcome